# Failed to load RxJs after updating Typescript to 2.5.3 and Rxjs to 5.5.0

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs5, package.json

I am referring Rxjs libraries to Angular 4 application. When I updated package.json references to latest version, thereafter application stop working with runtime application.

I made following major changes and update packages.

1. Angular: 4.4.6
2. rxjs: 5.5.0
3. typescript: 2.5.3

An error that I can see at browser console is as below.
[Rxjs error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEHlw.png)

For reference please find package.json contents as below.

```
{
  "name": "DX101",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/common": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/core": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/http": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/router": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/upgrade": "^4.4.6",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.3.2",
    "angular2-notifications": "^0.7.8",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.5.1",
    "del": "^3.0.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-live-server": "^0.0.30",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-sass-lint": "^1.3.4",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-tslint": "^8.1.2",
    "gulp-typescript": "^3.2.2",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.19.1",
    "popsicle": "^9.1.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "run-sequence": "^1.2.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.0",
    "systemjs": "^0.20.19",
    "systemjs-builder": "^0.16.12",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.4.6",
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.43",
    "@types/node": "^8.0.46",
    "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.3.0",
    "typescript": "^2.5.3",
    "typings": "^2.1.1"
  }
}
```

I am not sure what wrong has been done but error occurred after updating packages only.

Please help me understand and resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: It could be that one Library broke the other, or it could be that you need to update Zone Js

Comment: Possibly/likely related: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2971

Comment: How do you import the operator?

Comment: import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

Comment: Hey cartant, thanks a lot buddy! Your post help me to solve issue. I reverted to version 5.4.3 and my app started to work.